# ignoreAutoUpdate with p:clock

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using,

- PrimeFaces 4.0
- Mojarra 2.1.6
- GlassFish 3.1.2.2.

I'm using `<p:clock>` for displaying the date:

```
<p:clock pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"
         mode="server"
         autoSync="true"
         syncInterval="60000"/>
```

I would like to avoid other PF tags set with `autoUpdate="true"` to be updated when the synchronization happens (every minutes in that case).

From the doc there is no equivalent to the `<p:poll>` field `ignoreAutoUpdate` for `<p:clock>`.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer came from a PrimeFaces Core Developer: there is no solution. That would be a new feature for any future release.